# Autorotate while playing video from UIWebView to Landscape in iOS6

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios6, autorotate, ios6.1

I have four view controllers and have added into navigation controller in appDelegate.

I am supporting portrait mode only and its working in iOS6. One of the view controller has webview which is loading httprequest and displaying webpage. But while playing any video from webview with fullscreeen, my video hasn't gotten autorotate. I want to add landscape support while playing video only. After finished I want to come back to portrait mode.

How to do that for iOS6?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the window setRootViewCOntroller in your appDelegate (for IOS 6)

Then you should implement the IOS 6 autorotate, with that you will see that one of your autorotate method is getting called: shouldAutoRotate. you should return NO until the video is playing and then when the video is playing return YES.

I had the same problem with another app that is portrait all the time unless something is happen.